# How to pass a checkout StringBuilder object to a method?

Tags: java, string, methods, stringbuilder

I have a method and its require

```
private static someMethod initSomething(StringBuilder someString, int number){
   ...  
   someString = new StringBuilder();     <- ????
   this.someString.append(someString);   <- ????
}

initSomething("ddddd", 1234);
```

I just want to pass a string inside this method. And I don't like to use common String, because it is slower StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
private static someMethod initSomething(StringBuilder someString, int number){ 
   someString = new StringBuilder();     <- You just overwrote `someString`
   this.someString.append(someString);   <- Appending `someString`onto itself?
   // You are also missing `return`. And what is `someMethod`?
}
```

I modified the comments to the original code with observations and questions. I think what you wanted to do is something like this:

```
private static StringBuilder initSomething(String someString, int number){  
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append(someString);
   // more code here?
   return builder;
}
```

Alternatively, you can return a String like this:

```
return bulder.toString();
```

If instead you need to pass the `StringBuilder` object to the method, then you should do something like this:

```
private static String initSomething(StringBuilder builder, int number){
   builder.append(...);  <- what is being appended, number? You'll need to pass what is being appended to the method
   // more code here?
   return builder.toString();
}
```

All that said, your question is not clear at all. I am not completely sure what you want to solve. Hopefully this helps.